# AddTarget for custom view UIView is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom view class as follows

```
class AudioPlayerView: UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var playAudio: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var audioSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var deleteAudio: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var audioURL: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    commonInit()
}
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
func commonInit(){
    let viewFromXIB = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AudioPlayerView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
    viewFromXIB.frame = self.bounds
    addSubview(viewFromXIB)
}

}
```

I am adding the above view programmatically in a scroll view of view controller and setting up targets for buttons as follows

```
func addRecorderdAudioPlayerUI(){
    audioRecorderControlUIView.isHidden = true
    let audioPlayerView = AudioPlayerView()
    audioPlayerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 398, height: 50)
    
    audioPlayerView.audioSlider.addTarget(NoteViewController.self, action: #selector(changeAudioTime), for: .valueChanged)
    audioPlayerView.playAudio.addTarget(NoteViewController.self, action: #selector(playPauseAudioBtnCLicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    audioPlayerView.deleteAudio.addTarget(NoteViewController.self, action: #selector(deleteAudioBtnCLicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    audioPlayerView.audioURL.text = recordingsURLsToSave.last
    
    
    audioContainerScrollView.addSubview(audioPlayerView)
    scrollViewContentWidth += audioPlayerView.frame.width
    audioContainerScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContentWidth, height: 50)
}
```

I am able to add the view but the .touchUpInside targets are not working.

Comment: Change your `NoteViewController.self` to `self` and try.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1- replace `NoteViewController.self` with `self`

```
audioPlayerView.audioSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeAudioTime), for: .valueChanged)
audioPlayerView.playAudio.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPauseAudioBtnCLicked), for: .touchUpInside)
audioPlayerView.deleteAudio.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteAudioBtnCLicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

2- Add this method

```
class func getInstance() -> AudioPlayerView {
  let viewFromXIB = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AudioPlayerView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! AudioPlayerView   
  return  viewFromXIB 
}
```

Then replace

```
let audioPlayerView = AudioPlayerView()
```

with

```
let audioPlayerView = AudioPlayerView.getInstance()
```

Comment: tried this approach but no luck. It's not working not even hitting the breakpoint

Comment: I tried this and it throwed exception. Exception NSException * "[<iNotesPro.AudioPlayerView 0x105546650> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key audioSlider."

Comment: make sure you assigned class name `AudioPlayerView` to xib file

Comment: i made sure everything linked correctly. I did exactly as you said. But, again, no luck. its not even hitting breakpoint @Sh_Khan